# Microsoft XP Start Up

Tags: windows-xp

I have a AMD Athlon (tm) II X2 250 Processor where the operating system Windows XP is installed in. My Windows XP will not start up properly. It will not start up in Safe Mode itself with networking or with command prompt. And also Last known good configuration.  And sadly i dont have the Windows XP installation disc (got my tower case from a company that  went out of business)..Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What does it do when you try to start up, at what point does it fail?

Comment: When my PC starts up it goes to a black screen where i have to choose either start up option:Safe Mode, Safe Mode with Networking or command prompt and Last Known Good Configuration. All options didnt work..My PC would restart go back to.the same screen with all Safe.mode.options and last known good configuration.

Comment: With each option my PC just would restart over and go back to the same black screen.like i never choose an option.

Comment: It's not free, but consider treating this as an opportunity to upgrade to Windows 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

If the PC has a sticker with the OEM product key on the box you can downnload ISO of XP from many locations on the web and use it to re-install and re-register.

However if you don;t have the authenticity sticker with the key, the only way would be to buy official install media. Check ebay as sometime you can get a good deal - I have personally thrown the original XP OEM CD with a sticker to a trash 2 weeks ago

Comment: Apparently http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/ can "Load Hive" to inspect the registry of a dead Windows installation. So if you really had to, you could get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any modifications to the system like adding new hardware lately? If so try removing anything added and try restarting.